# I am trying to build an android application that use location information, but I am confused what to use foreground or background location permissions

Tags: android, background, location, android-permissions, foreground

I am trying to build an android application that use location information, but I am confused what to use foreground or background location permissions
my goal is to get location information always while the app is running even in the background and stop getting the location once the app is fully closed.
so what should I use? background or foreground location??

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, your app needs to have both the permissions, Foreground and Background.

You can follow this link for more details: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/location

Comment: Ok then, can you tell me what is the difference between them and when to use each one ??